# How do I intuitively prove the time complexity for this snippet of code

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I have a snippet code as follows:

```
int searchNumOccurrence(vector<int> &V, int k, int start, int end) {
    if (start > end) return 0;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (V[mid] < k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
    if (V[mid] > k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1);
    return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 +       searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
}
```

Analyzing intuitively, let us assume that all numbers in the array are = k. This would mean that we could go into recursion in the `return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1)` again and again. Assuming my start was 0 and end was N, this would execute *Log(N)* times. Same for the left part and answer would be *(2*Log(n))) = *Log(n)*.

However, the answer to this question in *O(N)*. While a theoretical proof would be okay I'm looking to really understand how this in *O(N)* intuitively.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Considering the worst case of identical numbers: your algorithm is going to *read all input* numbers: the middle element when comparing to it, then the first half and then the second half. To examine one element it needs O(1), so to examine `n` elements, it needs O(n).

Another way to look at it: look at the tree of function calls. This is going to be a binary tree (unlike binary search, where the "tree" is linear). The depth of this tree is `O(log n)`, while the number of nodes at each level is `O(2^i)`, where `i` is the nesting level. So the number of nodes at the deepest nesting level is `O(2^log(n))`, or `O(n)`.

Comment: I don't understand 2 things. First: How are we comparing all the numbers? Isn't it just log(n ) comparisons on both? Second, how is nesting on each level 2^i? Would appreciate if  you gave me an example thanks

Comment: If a call to the function returns x, then the final return statement must be executed exactly x times in total since those +1's are the only way the return value can be built up. That observation gives an easy proof that for an input array that's all k's will have runtime at least n (the length of the array).

Comment: @Solly I'll just answer the second question. Example: 15 elements. At nesting level 0 there is 1 function call, for 15 elements. At nesting level 1 there are 2 function calls, both for 7 elements. At nesting level 2 there are 4 function calls, all of them for 3 elements. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Say that the array A contains only the number 42, repeated 1000 times. Then calling `searchNumOccurrence(A, 42, 0, 999)` would return the value 1000. Every increment that lead to the number 1000 would come from one execution of “+ 1” in the last line. Hence, that line has to be executed 1000 = N times.

If the array contains distinct numbers, however, the algorithm acts like binary search and takes O(log N).